# Request for declined permissions. Unity for Facebook

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

Been trying to request for declined permission with FB.login("Scope") but it redirects me to the login page again. After logging in, it prompts me with a "You have already authorised APPNAME." FB.login doesn't support "auth_type".

Does anyone have any solutions to this problem?

Thanks~
May the force be with you

Comment: I would suggest filing a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs or see if it been reported there already

Answer (score 0):

Not sure for which platform you've been trying to re-ask declined permissions, probably for Canvas. I can only suggest solution for Android.

First, we need to hack provided `AndroidFacebook` and `FB` classes. To prevent overriding of our changes with plugin update in the future, we almost don't touch third party files, just make classes `partial`:

```
// AndroidFacebook.cs

namespace Facebook
{
    sealed partial class AndroidFacebook : AbstractFacebook, IFacebook
```

---

```
// FB.cs

public sealed partial class FB : ScriptableObject
```

Now we can extend existing classes with a couple of methods:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Facebook
{
    partial class AndroidFacebook
    {
        public void LoginWithParameters(IDictionary<string, object> parameters, FacebookDelegate callback = null)
        {
            if (parameters == null)
                parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            var paramJson = MiniJSON.Json.Serialize(parameters);
            AddAuthDelegate(callback);
            CallFB("Login", paramJson);
        }
    }
}

partial class FB
{
    public static bool TryLoginWithParametersOnAndroid(IDictionary<string, object> parameters, Facebook.FacebookDelegate callback = null)
    {
        var androidFacebook = FacebookImpl as Facebook.AndroidFacebook;
        if (androidFacebook == null)
            return false;
        androidFacebook.LoginWithParameters(parameters, callback);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here is how we can pass `scope` and `auth_type`:

```
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "scope", "email" },
    { "auth_type", "rerequest" },
};
var apiCallSucceeded = FB.TryLoginWithParametersOnAndroid(parameters, result =>
{
    ...
});
```

Comment: Hey @Qbit, thanks for the workaround - unfortunately it doesn't work for us using Facebook's Unity SDK v6.0 - we simply see the login screen opened for a second and then immediately closed without asking again for the declined permissions.

Do you have any clues to why this might happen? Thanks!